# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

I have a managed bean with view scope. The problem is that when I run the web application I have the following error:

```
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source).........
```

But when I change the scope to session or request, everything works just fine.
Can anyone tell my if I have done anything wrong? Maybe I forgot a configuration or something?

Answer (score 7):

You've assigned a JDBC `Connection` as a property of the view scoped managed bean. View scoped managed beans and all of its properties needs to be serializable as they will be stored in the session. The [`Connection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) interface does however not extend `Serializable` and hence this exception. You would need to make it `transient`.

But the *real* problem is actually bigger; holding external resources as a field of a class is an extremely bad idea. You should never hold DB resources as a field of a class which lives longer than the resource needs to be kept open. Otherwise they will leak away and/or will cause threadsafety and transactional problems (deadlocks and so on) and/or will be reclaimed by the DB and will thus stop working.

You should always open and close the connection (and statement and resultset) in the **shortest possible** scope, preferably inside a `try-finally` block of the very same method block. If you want to improve connecting performance, then you should be using a connection pool.

#### See also:

- [How often should Connection, Statement and ResultSet be closed in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602772/how-often-should-statement-and-resultset-objects-be-closed-in-jdbc)
- [JDBC MySql connection pooling practices to avoid exhausted connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313197/jdbc-mysql-connection-pooling-practices/2313262#2313262)
- [java jdbc mysql connector: how to resolve disconnection after a long idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148092/java-jdbc-mysql-connector-how-to-resolve-disconnection-after-a-long-idle-time/3148857#3148857)