# Keeping connection alive - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, dbexpress

I have set up my delphi application that I created with a button named `Connect`.
Once I click it it executes the following code:

```
begin
    someConnection.Connected:=true;
    somecomenziDataSet.Active:=true;
end;
```

Similarly I have a button for `Disconnect` purposes which does the same thing but with **=false;**

My problem is the database I'm connecting to is hosted on a shared hosting account and the mysql server has `wait_timeout` variable set to 60 seconds, `interactive_timeout` is set to 30 seconds.
Naturally, this disconnects me if I don't use my app for 60 seconds.

Is there any way to keep that connection alive?

Hosting company won't change the setting so i'm stuck with it.

I'm using RAD Studio 10 Seattle, `dbexpress` components, `TSQLConnection` and my database is `mysql`

Please do let me know in a comment if I left any necessary info out, thanks!

Comment: "ping" the database every 10 sec or so.

Comment: @kobik Could you provide a code example for this? I did come across mysql_ping in googling this and I thought about adding that to a TTimer but haven't yet found a code example on how to do this, make it an answer if you want so I can accept, I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Maybe @Kobik is thinking of doing a "SELECT 1" (which involves little server activity or network traffic).

Comment: @MartynA - wouldn't that interfere with the select statement i already have set up in my dataset?

Comment: It needn't - you could use a separate query component to do it.

Comment: You can have numerous queries sharing the same connection. Just create another query for the sole purpose of periodic activity.

Comment: Right, thanks guys :)

Comment: @MartynA, yes was basically what I had in mind. in ADO/SQL Server you could simply do: `TADOConnection.Execute(' ')` (space as command). maybe MySQL has similar. with `TSQLConnection` you could also do `TSQLConnection.Exceute` with the query you suggested.

Comment: I think a `TSQLConnection.Exceute('DO 0', nil)` in a timer will do the job.

Comment: @kobik Indeed, just found the property description - it keeps a connection active when no dataset is connected/active, that's about it. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `TTimer` to periodically "ping" the database (e.g. interval of 10-20 seconds given a 60 sec timeout):

```
procedure TMyDataModule.ConnectionPingTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not MySQLConnection.InTransaction then
    MySQLConnection.Execute('DO 0', nil); // or "SELECT 1" or whatever is cheapest
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works - just tested it. Is there any difference between DO 1 and DO 0 ? I found a nice discussion that uses DO 1 as an example and argues it's better (marginally faster) than a select 1 or a mysql_ping - any thoughts?

Comment: no difference between `DO 0` and `DO 1` which evaluates an expression without returning a value as opposed to `SELECT 0` or `SELECT 1` which return a result set. the differences in network traffic however  are neglectable. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2546868/937125

Comment: I see, yup, that's what I was reading, ok .. thanks for the answer : )

Comment: Typo in `Exceute`